# Understanding a specific WHERE clause in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, where-clause

I saw this as part of an Oracle SQL code

**where employer.eab_yr || employer.eab_no >= 20173
and employer.eab_yr || employer.eab_no <= 20202**

Can anyone explain to me what this part of the code is doing?

It appears it's fetching values from the employer table where eab_yr is between the 3rd month of 2017 and the second month of 2020. Is that correct?

Comment: what do the values in `eab_no` column look like? Do they look like month numbers? I don't like the code if they are as 201712 is numerically greater than 20186 for example

Comment: I have since realized that the eab.no part actually stands for quarters of the year (not months of the year) Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`||` is the string concatenation operator, `>=` is the greater than or equal operator and `<=` is the less than or equal operator.

So it matches all rows where the string concatenation of the columns `eab_yr` and `eab_no` of `employer` is numerically greater than or equal to `20173` and numerically less than or equal to `20202`.

That's all there is. What that means semantically cannot be answered without knowing the semantics of the relation(s (there might be more than one, we cannot tell as there was no `FROM` clause given)) and the attributes. You didn't disclose those.

Comment: Thanks. You've helped me figure out what the code is doing. Also, I have since realized that the eab.no part actually stands for quarters of the year (not months of the year) Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the code is concatenating year and month and trying to find a range then the code does not work as you would expect.

If you put the range from September 2017 to December 2017 then you will get the query:

```sql
where employer.eab_yr || employer.eab_no >= 20179
and   employer.eab_yr || employer.eab_no <= 201712
```

Now, `20201` is greater than the number `20179` and is less than the number `201712` so you would find that January 2020 is returned (and so would many other unexpected months).

If you want to fix it then use a 2-digit month:

```sql
where employer.eab_yr || LPAD( employer.eab_no, 2, '0' ) BETWEEN 201709 AND 201712
```

or use date literals:

```sql
where  TO_DATE( employer.eab_yr || '-' || employer.eab_no, 'YYYY-MM' )
         BETWEEN DATE '2017-09-01' AND DATE '2017-12-01'
```

or, even better, fix your table so that you have a single `DATE` column rather than individual `year` and `month` columns.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f006764e05fd49b70f6b50a36c9f759a)*

Comment: Thanks. I have since figured out that the eab.no part actually stands for quarters of the year (not months of the year)
Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4
Thanks for your insights